# If else and return

Tags: php, boolean

Is it possible to make this in 1 line ?

Here is my code

```
    if(!is_null($id)){
        return TRUE;
    }
    else{
        return FALSE;
    }
```

Thank's for the help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`is_null()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) already returns a boolean type, so you can simply write:

```
return !is_null($id);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

```
return (!is_null($id)) ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can:

```
return (!is_null($id)) ? true : false;
```

Or just remove breaks:

```
if (!is_null($id)){ return TRUE; } else { return FALSE; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah:

```
return is_null($id) ? FALSE : TRUE
```

which reads as:

[return] [the statement] ? [if is true, do this] : [otherwise, do this]

Answer (score 1):

Use ternary operator.

```
return (!is_null($id)) ? TRUE : FALSE;
```